# Unable to convert a pandas Dataframe to a list using literal_eval

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to convert a pandas Dataframe column to a list as the data in the column is being read as a str by default.
Sample data in the dataframe 'movie' column 'genres' is

```
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
```

The code I am writing

```
import ast 
import pandas as pd
movie = pd.read_csv("tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
movie['genres'] = movie['genres'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(str(x)))
print(type(movie['genres']))
```

The output I am getting is

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Really can't wrap my head around where am I going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame`s are composed of `Series` objects (where a `Series` is simply a column. Series are container objects similar to Python lists and can actually be converted into a `list` by using their [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method.

`ast.literal_eval` is being applied on each element inside of your Series, converting them a `string` into `dictionary`, those dictionaries as then stored back into a `Series`.

So pretty much your code is working- but if you want a `list` of dictionaries instead of a `Series` of dictionaries, you'll need to the following:

```py
import ast 
import pandas as pd
movie = pd.read_csv("tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
movie['genres'] = movie['genres'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(str(x)))

genres = movie['genres'].tolist()
print(genres)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I'm trying to run the code line below it still gives out the result as False 
import ast 
import pandas as pd
movie = pd.read_csv("tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
movie['genres'] = movie['genres'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(str(x)))
print(isinstance(movie['genres'][0], dict))